# A node just to act as sync point / checkpoint server

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I've created a small private blockchain with 3 full nodes 100% synced (1 Exec, 1 Consensus and 1 Validator each). All are working fast and smooth like a charm.

Now I need to keep another nodes just to be used as a kind of sync server / checkpoint server to guarantee the chain data without hard work (light servers with low cpu/ram). Maybe act as boot node too.

I think all I need is to run the Execution (Geth) and add it as trusted peer to all other Geth.

Am I correct? Do I need to run the Beacon too?

Answer (score 0):

You do need to run both the execution and the consensus clients. You can run a client that does both, like [Helios](https://github.com/a16z/helios)

Comment: Thanks... I'm concerning about ```Warning Helios is still experimental software....```

Comment: Have we a Docker version ?

Comment: What's the benefit of using another product in my stack instead of going up with a Prysm Consensus like the other nodes?